# In a PySide2 app, how can I get the ID for a QWindow?

Tags: python, qt5, maya, pyside2

In the version of PySide2 that ships with Maya2017, the `winId` method on the QWindow class seems to be missing:

```
w.winId()
Error: AttributeError: file <maya console> line 1: 'PySide2.QtGui.QWindow' object has no attribute 'winId' #
```

Is there a way to get this value from an existing instance of QWindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Maya 2018 for macOS 10.11.6. Try this code. It works.

```
from maya import OpenMayaUI as omui 

try:
  from PySide2.QtCore import * 
  from PySide2.QtGui import * 
  from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
  from PySide2 import __version__
  from shiboken2 import wrapInstance 
except ImportError:
  from PySide.QtCore import * 
  from PySide.QtGui import * 
  from PySide import __version__
  from shiboken import wrapInstance 

mayaMainWindowPtr = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow() 
mayaMainWindow= wrapInstance(long(mayaMainWindowPtr), QWidget) 

w = QLabel("Hello, Window", parent=mayaMainWindow) 
w.setObjectName('Label1') 
w.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window)
w.show()
```

And after typing:

```
w.winId()
```

you'll get something like this:

```
# Result: 140640756092816 #
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Andy's example works for me in both Maya2018 and the latest release of Maya2017, but throws an exception in at least the initial release of Maya 2017.

I expect the problem was caused by a bug in PySide2 that got fixed along the way.