# Shiboken2 and custom Qt widget

Tags: c++, windows, python-3.x, qt5, pyside2

On Windows, I need to use in Python a few custom Qt5 widgets written in C++, and I have to use `pyside2` because of its license.

I have been able to compile the `pyside2` library from source (together with the `shiboken2` examples), but I am not able to find a simple example of how to wrap a custom Qt5 widget.

I am aware that `pyside2` is still not officially released, but it seems to be already used (e.g., in Maya): [In a PySide2 app, how can I get the ID for a QWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46290088/2741329)

Can anybody give hints or directions? A minimal example would be even better.

---

**Edits**

Based on @placinta comments, I have created a [repo](https://github.com/giumas/shiboken2_minimal) with a minimal example that attempts to wrap a custom `QMainWindow`.

In my tests, I have used the `pyside2` [Conda package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyside2) that wraps `Qt` 5.6.

When I execute the `shiboken2` executable, I am getting [tons of warnings](https://github.com/giumas/shiboken2_minimal/issues/1).

I assume that these warnings are triggering a [compilation error](https://github.com/giumas/shiboken2_minimal/issues/2) with the `shiboken2` generated code.

Comment: This is not really a complete answer, thus I post it as a comment. You can use the scriptableapplication example as a reference. It is located in the 5.9 branch of the pyside examples repo git://code.qt.io/pyside/examples.git .
The example creates bindings for a QMainWindow-derived class among other things. The shiboken invocation is done by qmake when processing the scriptableapplication.pro file, which process the .xml typesystem file.

Comment: @Placinta Thanks! Are you using `shiboken2` in a project?

Comment: No, I'm a developer of PySide2.

Comment: @Placinta, this is great! It would be great if you could find the time to develop your comment into a complete answer.

Comment: @gmas80 https://github.com/giumas/shiboken2_minimal not found

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry! just made it public

Comment: @eyllanesc I may have found a workaround by modifying the CMake: https://github.com/giumas/shiboken2_minimal/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem with my initial CMake configuration was the one described [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/67583-CMake3-6-VS2015-Qt5-7-lost-in-function-pointer-based-signals-slots-across-DLLs).  That is, CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS has limitations so I reverted to use 'old' [export headers](https://github.com/giumas/shiboken2_minimal/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L39).

However, the compilation error for the missing `metaObject()` member function declaration is still present. It works by manually adding the declaration since the implementation is present in the `_wrapper.cpp`. Although it is not really a satisfying solution, it is a starting point for other users.

A Qt ticket for the issue at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-597 .